# Override Tooltip for List Mode = Delete

Tags: sapui5

I have a [List](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.ListBase/controlProperties) with the [mode](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.ListMode) `Delete`. Is there a way to override the tooltip for the delete button?

[image: This tooltip I will override]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where the magic happens: [sap.m.ListBase.prototype.getDeleteControl](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/04bedea798838106180e247032d60be196813477/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/ListItemBase.js)

You could easily override this and change the tooltip to sth. else. Don't forget to keep calling the original method for future compatibility:

```
var fnOriginal = sap.m.ListItemBase.prototype.getDeleteControl
sap.m.ListItemBase.prototype.getDeleteControl = function() {
  var oDelIcon = fnOriginal.apply(this, arguments);
  oDelIcon.setTooltip("My fancy tooltip");
  return oDelIcon;
}
```

**Disclaimer:** Be aware that this API is PRIVATE and can be subject to future change which will potentialy break your code. The least that could happen is that your tooltip stops working.

HF Chris